# How can i use Dictionary.Any(Function(x)) with a List(of(keyvaluepair(of String, String) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list, linq, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I'm currently using the following code and it works very well, at getting the paragraphs from a Word document that matches the keywords on my dictionary, the only problem is that dictionaries don't allow duplicates, i want to know how could i use a List(of(keyvaluepair(of string, string) the same way im using the dictionary at the where clause.

Examples:
Working perfectly with the dictionary, except some, there are duplicates in key with the same value that I need to place.

```
    filelistDict.Add("date", "Date")
    filelistDict.Add("july", "Date")
    filelistDict.Add("1", "Date")
    filelistDict.Add("1", "Number")
    filelistDict.Add("one", "Number")


        Dim matchQuery4 = From para As Paragraph In doc.Paragraphs
                          Where filelistDict.Any(Function(s) Regex.IsMatch(para.Range.Text, "(_|-)" + Regex.Escape(s.Key) + "|\b" + Regex.Escape(s.Key) + "\b|" + Regex.Escape(s.Key) + "(_|-)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                          Select para
```

I want to achieve the same result but with the following list, which allows the duplicates but I don't know how to implement in the linq code.

```
 Dim WordsDictionary As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))

 Dim matchQuery4 = From para As Paragraph In doc.Paragraphs
                          Where WordsDictionary.Any(Function(s) Regex.IsMatch(para.Range.Text, "(_|-)" + Regex.Escape(s.Key) + "|\b" + Regex.Escape(s.Key) + "\b|" + Regex.Escape(s.Key) + "(_|-)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                          Select para
```

Comment: Have you tested anything? What makes you think it won't work?

Comment: Yeah i have do some test, the problem is i haven't find a way to access from the Function(s) the objects within the list. Additionally lists doesn't have a method called Any. I believe if i could make it look at the object within i will be able to use any, but no luck so far.

Comment: `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and this will enable the use of the `bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)` under the namespace `System.Linq`. Are you sure you're not missing the using directive?

Comment: Sorry, the language you're using is VB so if you import the namespace `System.Linq` in the beginning of the file you'll have access to the extension method 
`Public Function Any(Of T)(source as IEnumerable(Of T)) As Boolean`
In fact, when you're using `filelistDict.Any` you're using the exact same extension method, since dictionaries do not implement a method called Any, it just implements `ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue))` which in turn inherits from `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue))`